# Hypothesis testing,difference between variances

Tags: statistical-inference

It is suspected that the variance of the distribution of distances in kilometers that a model
new car equipped with a diesel engine runs on 5 liters of fuel is
less than the variance of the distance distribution covered by the same model
equipped with a 6-cylinder gasoline engine, which is known to be 
2 = 6.25. Yes 72
test runs with the diesel model have a variance of 4.41, can we conclude,
at a significance level of 0.05, that the variance of the distances traveled by the model
that runs on diesel is less than that of the model that runs on gasoline? Suppose
the data come from a population that is Normally distributed. Consider in your answer
the  -  calculation of the test.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsbQM.jpg)

The teacher say my method is wrong. Is she right?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsbQM.jpg)

Comment: You should be conducting a [$\chi^2$-test for variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance), not a $z$-test.

Comment: Here are this answer https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/probability-and-statistics-for-engineers-and-scientists-8th-edition-chapter-10-problem-72e-solution-9780131877115?trackid=e1ae67d27a3c&strackid=88ab31ab5b85

Comment: Z = (s –σ)/ σ/√(2n)?